# Catastrophic error when using abstract interfaces and declared parametrized types

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

```
  module test2
     implicit none
     integer :: ts

  end module test2


  module test1
  implicit none

  type :: ty2(t_size )
      integer, len :: t_size
      real :: x(t_size )
  end type


  type :: ty1(t_size )
      integer, len :: t_size
      real :: x(t_size )
  end type


  abstract interface
  subroutine dummy( dat1 )
     use test2
     import ty1
     implicit none
     type(ty1(t_size=ts)), intent(inout) :: dat1

  end subroutine
  end interface


  end module

  program test

  use test2

  ts = 10




  end program
```

Can anybody tell me why this does not work?

I can tell you that what triggers the error is `type(ty1(t_size=ts)), intent(inout) :: dat1`

If I instead declare ts as a parameter, it works, but it seems not to accept the other way where it is dynamic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "catastrophic" do you mean that is what the (Intel?) compiler says?  Please put the entire message here in the question.

Comment: Parameterized derived types are particularly hard for compiler vendors to get right.  Supporting an automatic PDT, as here, is tricky.  If this is indeed an internal compiler error, there's not much to do beyond: report; use later version; try to write code that does what you want without hitting the bug; use another compiler.

Comment: Also please give your compiler version.  This code compiles for me using 17.0 and 18.0.

Comment: Sorry I am using 15.0 - that might be the reason

Comment: That is really old, you have to update.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is simply a compiler bug which has been fixed in recent releases.  Working around this bug for older versions would be too specific to answer here.